# How to close date picker which opens automatically?

Tags: javascript, css, datepicker

I created a date picker in my code but this opens up automatically. How do I prevent this?

I have used the javascript component from here [Date Range Picker](https://www.daterangepicker.com/)

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[name="updateDat"]').daterangepicker({
      singleDatePicker: true,
      showDropdowns: true,
      autoApply: true,
      minYear: 2017,
      maxYear: parseInt(moment().format('YYYY'), 10),
      "locale": {
        "format": "DD.MM.YYYY"
      },
    },
    function(start, end, label) {
      console.log(start.format("DD.MM.YYYY"))
      //window.localStorage.setItem("updateDw", start.format("DD.MM.YYYY"))
    });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
<body>
  <input type="text" name="updateDat" id="updateDate" />
</body>
```

Comment: what opens up automatically

Comment: When i open the page the daterangepicker is opened without pressing it. I need it to be opened only if someone presses it.

Comment: can you please share the full code, this code works fine in my browser.

Comment: Yes i checked at js fiddle it works fine. But i can't share my whole code only code about the date picker is here. Is there a way of closing this datepicker with programatic way?

Comment: ok let me check it once, i am asking the full code because sometimes if you have set the input focus from css or other js code it might cause the date picker to open automatically

Comment: Programmatically closing the picker is a bit hackish. The picker shows up when the input gets focus, try to find some code gaining focus to the input. It's also possible, that there's autofocus happening when the page is loaded, in that case you've to prevent that.

Comment: @Teemu is right,please check whether your input is getting focused automatically at onload

Comment: I may have found the cause. This input is inside of a modal. If i press a button on the main page a modal opens up and in this process also the date picker opens up. But i cant see why this would effect the date picker. The modal is a semantic ui modal.

Comment: Maybe depending on the browser, but in many browsers the first input element gets focus when the page loads. Without the rest of the code we can't say, you've to investigate this by yourself.

Comment: Okay thank you for your help :)

Comment: maybe you can use the JQuery blur() method to remove focus